# How to apply multiple conditions for columns in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, shift, cumsum

I have a data frame that looks as shown below and there is no relationship between the two columns

| item | col1 |
| --- | --- |
| cat | 1 |
| cat | 1 |
| dog | 1 |
| fish | 1 |
| fish | 1 |
| fish | 2 |
| snake | 2 |
| snake | 2 |
| snake | 2 |

I want to generate a new column using these two. The resulting column should do a cumulative sum for the items column (increments number only when the item changes) and also the number must start from 1 again if the series in col1 has a change.

| item | col1 | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cat | 1 | 1 |
| cat | 1 | 1 |
| dog | 1 | 2 |
| fish | 1 | 3 |
| fish | 1 | 3 |
| fish | 2 | 1 |
| snake | 2 | 2 |
| snake | 2 | 2 |
| snake | 2 | 2 |

I was able to do the cumulative sum with the below code,

```
df["result"] = (df["item"] != df["item"].shift(1)).cumsum()
```

But the condition to reset the counter to 1 when there is a change in col1 is something I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check with `groupby` and `factorize` within `transform`

```
df['new'] = df.groupby('col1').item.transform(lambda x : x.factorize()[0]+1)
df
    item  col1  new
0    cat     1    1
1    cat     1    1
2    dog     1    2
3   fish     1    3
4   fish     1    3
5   fish     2    1
6  snake     2    2
7  snake     2    2
8  snake     2    2
```

Comment: Can someone help me understand why there is a +1 at the end of the code?